# Using Standard REGEX to add a character at the end of a string

Tags: replace, addition

I need to add a backslash "\" to a string before storing it;

e.g. source "user1@domain1" - is stored in two variables: userid and domain. For the domain variable, before storing it, I want to add a backward slash to the end of the domain name e.g. "domain1\". How can this be done in regex?

Comment: Please be more specific. You probably do not need a regex for this. What language are you using?

Comment: Also, please include which programming language you are using. There isn't really any "standard" for regex, though PCRE would probably be close.

Answer (score 0):

With standard regex you can add anything with 'echo'. Just note for a backslash and other characters, you have to use an escape character, which happens to also be a backslash.

```
echo domain\\
```

To split the string, use [a method described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10638538/split-string-with-bash-with-symbol). I'll post my favorite for your case.

```
string='user1@domain1'
IFS=@ read left right <<< "$string"
echo "$left"
echo "$right\\"
```

gives an output of the username on the first line, and 'domain1\' on the second.